# How to only keep first part of number within a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
column1
411/711
589
90/11
```

How do I only keep the number before the slash?

New df looks like this:

```
column1
411
589
90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `split`

```
df.column1=df.column1.str.split('/').str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand into multiple columns and select the first:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.split('/', n=1, expand=True)[0].astype(int)

print(df['column1'])

0    411
1    589
2     90
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```